# Is a Ledger Live Native ADA App with Staking and Voting Functionality in Development?

Tags: wallet, staking, ledger, voting

Is a Ledger Live native ADA app with staking and voting functionality in development? If so is there any place to check periodically for road map updates?

I believe IOG has a team that works with exchanges and I'm guessing a Ledger team as well, but I'm not sure who/where to follow for updates.

Thanks for your support!
-CPG

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no development on these functionality from the Ledger team.